# Change the navtab height in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, height, navbar

Is there any way to change the nav-tabs height?
My mission is to set the height so I can insert a picture to this bar.

Answer (score 0):

To change only the height of the Boostrap navbar, you just need to do this:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    height: 70px; /* Whatever you want. */
}
```

Comment: thanks- but i need to change the nav-tab not the navbar

Answer (score 0):

```
CSS

li{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0px;
    height:43px;
}
li.active{
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="tabbable" >
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" ><!--tabs-->
          <li style="" id="logintab">
               <a href="#pane_login" data-toggle="tab" id="logintab_a">Login</a></li>
          <li class="active" id="reg_tab" >
              <a href="#pane_reg" data-toggle="tab" id="regtab_a">Registration</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content"><!--login tab content-->
        <div id="pane_login" class="tab-pane active">
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-content"><!--login tab content-->
        <div id="pane_register" class="tab-pane active">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Its changed the distance between the green line and the tab but not the height of the bar himself.I want to insert a large photo to each tab.